# Acessar página e fazer login com Curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer o login com Curl em páginas da web usando o código mais simples possível mais nunca dá certo mesmo o código estando aparentemente correto segue o código:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email=teste@hotmail.com&pass=senha123');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo = $store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele não funciona porque o Facebook exige que envie mais informações. Simplesmente monitorando o trafego de rede você consegue ver que o "Login" é feito em:

```
https://m.facebook.com/login/async/
```

Ele também envia um monte de dados e não simplesmente "email" e "password":

```
m_ts: 
li: 
try_number:
unrecognized_tries:
email: 
pass:
m_sess:
fb_dtsg:
lsd:
__dyn:
__req:
__ajax__:
__user:
```

---

Se desabilitar o Javascript ele utilizará o `https://m.facebook.com/login.php`, o mesmo apontado pelo seu cURL, porém contendo no corpo as informações:

```
lsd:
m_ts:
li:
try_number:
unrecognized_tries:
email:
pass:
login:
_fb_noscript:
```

Logo, você precisa descobrir como eles são gerados o que significam e então reproduzir isto no cURL, assim conseguirá fazer o login.

Se continuar enviando apenas `email` e `pass` você nunca irá conseguir acessar, ao menos não seria lógico o Facebook permitir isto, talvez algumas informações podem não ser enviadas, mas isto terá de ser testado um a um.

*Lembre-se que o Facebook possui uma API usando OAuth, que é muito mais seguro do que utilizar login/senha.*